# Is my simulation result for unpolarized light correct?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization, maxwell-equations

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83822/18778). After that, I picked up some knowledge of FDTD (an algorithm for solving Maxwell's equations) and simulated following scene:

***Pic 1***

[image]

As the picture shows, a silicon cone ($r=5 μm, θ=30°$) is placed in vacuum (truncated with [PML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectly_matched_layer)). Incident light ($λ=532 nm$) is perpendicular to the bottom of the cone. In my simulation the incident light is modeled as a electric field hard source placed at the bottom of the cone and its electric field intensity obeys Gaussian distribution i.e.

$$E\left(x,y,z_0\right)=A_0 \sin (2 \pi  f t) e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{w^2}}$$

Here $E$ can be either $E_x$, $E_y$, $E_z$, $z=z_0$ is the plane at which the bottom surface of the cone is.

The whole domain is discretized with 200×200×400 uniform grids ($\Delta x=\Delta y=\Delta z=50 nm$), along with 20-grid-thick PML layer enclosing it.

Here's my simulation result of the light intensity ($|E|^2$) at the plane $100 nm$ away from the tip of the cone for z-polarized light *(notice that the z-axis is parallel to the central axis of the cone in my coordinates)*:

***Pic 2***

[image: dd]

and y-polarized light:

***Pic 3***

[image]

So here comes the confusion. As [Steve B](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/3811/steve-b) suggest in his answer, "the intensity for unpolarized light is the average of the intensity in the two simulations (for polarized light)", but since this two result is… not independent of the rotational orientation of polarization analyzer (if there exists one), a simple average of them won't be, too:

***Pic 4***

[image]

*This is the average of z-polarized and y-polarized result, it's almost the same as that of the y-polarized light because that of z-polarized one is in fact very weak.*

So the unpolarized light is no longer unpolarized after it passes the cone?

Moreover, it's not hard to realize that simulation result for x-polarized light is just the same as the y-polarized one, only a 90° rotation needed, so the average of x-polarized and y-polarized light is:

***Pic 5***

[image]

Still, the picture don't have full rotational symmetry, what's more, it's different from the average of the z-polarized and y-polarized one! So I'll get different simulation result for unpolarized light with different average method?

Is my way to "take the average" wrong? Or it's just the truth?

My code isn't contained in this post for its lengthiness. I think it's trivial since it has been checked for times and nothing seems to be wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**<strike>Wrong Guess</strike> Update 1:**

In the comments below, [DumpsterDoofus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/30717/dumpsterdoofus) and [Ruslan](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/21441/ruslan) guessed that the PML I used in the model maybe not work as expected i.e. the lack of full rotational symmetry of my image may be caused by the reflection of the boundary I use.

If this guess is correct, the image I get will be different when I change the size of simulation domain, so I tried two more simulation, and the result, in a word, proves negative.

To make the simulation faster, I've chose a smaller cone ($r=\frac{5}{2} μm, h=\frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{4}μm $) this time. Two domains with different sizes (200×200×100 grids and 120×120×70 grids) are used in the two simulations separately. Another tiny change is that this time I've turned to additive source instead of the hard source used in the simulation above. Grid size and the thickness of the PML layer (for this part, see my edit above) remains the same as that of the simulation above.

Here's how the whole domain looks like in the two simulations (the sizes of the cones are same).

Domain formed with 200×200×100 grids:

***Pic 6***

[image]

Domain formed with 120×120×70 grids:

***Pic 7***

[image]

And here's the result (the picture is still taken at the plane $100 nm$ away from the tip):

y-polarized light (simulation result of the larger domain):

***Pic 8***

[image]

y-polarized light (simulation result of the smaller domain):

***Pic 9***

[image]

Supposed unpolarized light (simulation result of the larger domain):

***Pic 10***

[image]

Supposed unpolarized light (simulation result of the smaller domain):

***Pic 11***

[image]

Apparently there is no significant difference except the spot size(**Note:** I forgot to adjust the `DataRange` of `ListDensityPlot` 囧, and I decide not to modify it in the following part of this post), and we still don't have full rotational symmetry.

---

**<strike>Wrong Guess</strike> Update 2:**

[Ruslan](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/21441/ruslan) then suggested that the round source I chose may generate unequally widening wave in x and y direction depending on polarization i.e. it maybe not work as expected.

If this guess is correct, the simulation result won't show perfect symmetry even if I remove the cone i.e do the simulation in an empty space. So I simulated the y-polarized light in vacuum without the cone, and the result shows perfect symmetry, so the source seems to work as expected.

The following picture shows how the whole domain looks like in this simulation (formed with 120×120×70 grids):

***Pic 12***

[image]

Here's the result (taken at same place as ***pic 9***):

***Pic 13***

[image]

Comment: What would first surprise me is not lack of any rotational invariance of the intensities, but the difference of pictures of intensities. If I understand you correctly, the difference between two images should just be rotation of $\vec E$ by $\frac\pi2$, because you just rotated the source around cone axis, and the medium has symmetry with respect to rotation by arbitrary angle around this axis. But what you present is completely incompatible with this. How does your picture change if you continuously rotate the polarization angle from $0$ to $\frac\pi2$?

Comment: @Ruslan The difference between the two image is indeed a rotation of $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{E}$ by $\frac{\pi }{2}$, but it's not rotated around cone axis, z-axis in my coordinates is parallel to the cone axis while y-axis is perpendicular to it. My original description seems to be a little obscure, edited  :)

Comment: Hmm. How could light in vacuum be polarized in the direction of propagation?

Comment: @Ruslan  !(Check the wikipedia…) Sorry for my poor basis of physics. Well, my original description isn't quite precise, in fact when simulating the incident light is just modeled as a electric source placed at the bottom face of the cone. By the way, the intensity for z-polarized light is in fact very weak, when compared with that of y-polarized light, it's almost masked. Still, even if I choose x-polarized and y-polarized light for my modeling of unpolarized light, my question mentioned above still exists.

Comment: Well, I still didn't get the idea of your initial conditions. What starting field $\vec E(x,y,z)$, $\vec B(x,y,z)$ do you have? What boundary conditions do you impose on the system — and this for both cases of polarization? And I have checked Wikipedia before asking you how you have longitudinal component of light wave in free vacuum.

Comment: @Ruslan The initial condition is a surface electric field source at the bottom face of the cone i.e. $E\left(x,y,z_0\right)=A_0 \sin (2 \pi  f t) e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{w^2}}$($z=z_0$ is the bottom surface), and for FDTD only the starting field of $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{E}$ is needed(it's a leap-frog scheme). I've chose [PML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectly_matched_layer) for the truncation of the free space.

Comment: Is your Gaussian beam polarized or unpolarized?  If it's unpolarized, I'd be curious to see what a plot of $I_x + I_y$ looks like.  Can you provide it?

Comment: Better:  Create a vector plot (arrows, or something) of $E_x\hat{x} + E_y\hat{y}$ and see if the resulting plot is rotationally symmetric.

Comment: @garyp In a single simulation the source is polarized, but the final target of these simulation is to get the light intensity distribution for unpolarized Gaussian beam throughout the cone. I've added the $I_x+I_y$ picture, have a look.

Comment: At this point your question has gotten so long as to be daunting.  In my browser it spans 5-6 pages.  Could you combine some of your figures into a grid and combine all of the updates into one coherent question?

Comment: @ChrisMueller Sorry, I didn't notice your comment (there're so many comments that day). I've moved part of the update into the answer and modified some of the description in the question to make it more readable. As for the suggestion of combining the figure in to a grid, I have to say it's hard for me now because I've deleted almost all of the raw data (they're too large! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Ruslan](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/21441/ruslan) , precisely speaking, what one should do to simulate the unpolarized light is to take an average of the intensity of all the orthogonal polarized light other than just 2 of them. Plane source is a special case because its z-polarized component is quite weak so it won't hurt even if only an average of x and y-polarized component is taken.

But wait, in ***Pic 4***,  OP has already taken an average of all 3 component, why he still can't get full rotational symmetry?

The answer is really simple but easy to ignore: the grid isn't dense enough, so it has formed a not-really-round cone.

After halving the grid size (with other condition remaining the same as ***Pic 9*** and ***Pic 11***), we got the following result:

y-polarized light (with same condition as ***Pic 9***, except for a denser grid):

***Pic 14***

[image]

Supposed unpolarized light (with same condition as ***Pic 11***, except for a denser grid):

***Pic 15***

[image]

z-polarized light:

***Pic 16***

[image]

*Light intensity here is in fact very weak, the simulation result of passing rate is about 0.08%. BTW, grids for this simulation still seems to be not dense enough, but it's not a big deal.*

---

To avoid any possible confusion, here is a more accurate simulation result of the z-polarized case:

z-polarized light (with same condition as ***Pic 16***, except for a denser grid, $\Delta x=\Delta y=\Delta z=12.5 nm$):

***Pic 17***

[image]

*Though still defective, the simulation result almost gains full rotational symmetry, being much better than **Pic 16**. The passing rate is about 0.04%.*

Answer (score 3):

As Ruslan said, your error lies in the fact that you used z-polarized light. There is no such thing as z-polarized light (it doesn't exist).

Comment: Sorry for my obscure description, see my comment above.

Comment: @xzczd: You say that using the $x$ and $y$ polarizations, the problem still exists. I assume the $x$ polarized light looks like a $\pi/2$ rotation of the $y$-polarized picture you provided? I'm noticing that the pictures have the symmetry group of the boundaries (reflection symmetry). What happens when you widen the boundaries? It might be a boundary problem.

Comment: Yeah, your guess for the x-polarized light is right. The cone is modeled as being placed in infinite space, with the help of [PML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectly_matched_layer).

Comment: Do you take PML as frequency-dependent? Gaussian wave, especially originating from a 2D source, is far from a monochromatic wave, so you may get reflection from a single-frequency PML. This may be the reason for lack of full rotational symmetry of your images. Try indeed to considerably expand your boundaries.

Comment: Gaussian beams have a decomposition into plane waves, and the $k$ vectors of those plane waves do not all point in the $z$ direction. Also, once the beam reflects off of a wall, there will be $z$ components to the $E$ field.

Comment: @Ruslan Particularly speaking, what I've chose is [CPML](http://www.engr.uky.edu/~gedney/roden_gedney_cpml_motl.pdf), which is claimed to be……quite good? Well, to be honest, I don't quite understand the advantages mentioned in the introductions of it. (For this part I've referred to the _Computationai Electrodynamics The Finite Difference Time Domain Method_ by _Allen Taflove_. )

Comment: Have you tried expanding the boundaries? Maybe even try this for empty space with various volumes, it'll already give us a clue whether the boundaries are the reason of problem.

Comment: @Ruslan You mean I may have some luck by enlarging the computational domain i.e. make the cone farther away from the PML?

Comment: Yes, precisely this

Comment: @Ruslan The result proves negative. See my update for details.

Comment: @xzczd Aha, so the PML does work as intended. OK. My next guess would be that your initial wave packet has anisotropic intensity xy plane. If I understand your description correctly, you have a round source of oscillating x/y polarized E-field. It seems it could generate unequally widening wave in x and y direction, depending on polarization. Do you get a isotropic image if you remove the cone (leave empty space)? Alternatively, try using a pre-generated wave packet instead of a field source and see if it gives better results.

Comment: @xzczd BTW, what do you mean by "additive source instead of the hard source"?

Comment: @Ruslan OK, another several hours to wait :) As to the additive source part, have a look at P48 of [this document](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~schneidj/ufdtd/chap3.pdf), in the code it's in fact only a difference of `=` and `+=`. For some silly reason, I've chose hard source in my first simulation, while an additive source is more close to the beam I'm trying to model. Theoretically it's trivial here, and it is: the result still lacks full rotational symmetry.

Comment: @Ruslan BTW, what do you mean by "using a pre-generated wave packet"? Does it mean setting non-zero initial conditions i.e. something like $E(x, y, z)|_{t=0} =\ldots, H(x, y, z)|_{t=0} =\ldots$ for Maxwell's equations? If so, at top of P41 of the document I linked above, it's suggested not to be used, and according to my test, this approach is indeed more likely to introduce numeric errors.

Comment: @xzczd they say "cumbersome and not _typically_ a good approach". Of course, I don't say you're in a typical situation :) For a test this could be not a problem. As for what I mean by this suggestion, it's not quite initialize at zero: you have E & H at staggered points, so you'd initialize E at one point in time and H at another - with correspondingly shifted wave packet. I think there's analytical expression for gaussian evolution in free space, which would be good enough for this task.

Comment: @Ruslan OK, but the simulation for the source in vacuum has already finished (since it's in vacuum, it takes less time), it shows perfect symmetry, so the source seems to work as expected, see my update for details. BTW, I've noticed another possibility, that's, my grid maybe a little scarce (roughly 10 points per wavelength in vacuum, 7 points per wavelength in cone), so I decided to halve the grid size and see the result. (This time it'll be really slow, 16 times the time needed for the previous simulation 囧)

Comment: @xzczd indeed, this seems a good guess. Maybe it'd be even better to use grid with another group of symmetry (e.g. hexagonal — or even irregular, with refinements near media interface) to really see the difference. I'd think what you get currently is wrong symmetry of refractions from not-really-round cone, so the interface must be what matters most.

Comment: @Ruslan The grid is indeed a little scarce…… OK, now there remains the last question, see my update of the question for details.

Comment: @xzczd Well, for a point source near the object you'll have to include all three polarizations to compute final intensity — right because z-polarized component may no longer be negligible. For a round source, these components were mostly cancelling out by surface integration of fields (but but not totally because of finite surface sizes), and for point source there's only one point, so z-component should not be neglected.

Comment: @xzczd BTW, I hope you'll do answer your own question when all your questions are solved — so that it didn't remained unanswered.

Comment: @Ruslan: Agreed, my answer isn't particularly helpful (other than pointing out an obvious initial problem) so it's probably best if either you or xzczd provide the final answer.

Comment: @Ruslan Yeah, in the last simulation the z-polarized one is indeed not negligible. (the passing rate is about 11% and that for y-polarized light is about 17%. ) So generally speaking, if I understand correctly, what I should do to simulate the unpolarized light is to take an average of the intensity of all the orthogonal polarized light other than just 2 of them, the plane source is just a special case because its z-polarized component is quite weak, right?

Comment: @Ruslan If my understanding above is right, I'll wait for a while and answer the question myself if no one is interested in this chance to get some reputation :)

Comment: @xzczd yeah, you're right. As for chance to get reputation — I think no one will read to the end of the question, so I doubt anyone will want to answer. It'd be best if you moved some of your updates to the question into the answer.

Comment: @Ruslan It took me several days to get a better simulation result of z-polarized case. Without all your help it'll be harder for me to find the answer so I turned my answer to a community wiki. Thanks for all!