# Difference between unpolarized beam and half H+V polarized beam

Tags: photons, measurements, polarization

Let's say that we have got two light beams. Beam A is not polarized at all. Beam B is composed of half H polarized photons + half V polarized photons.

Is there any way to measure those two beams in order to distinguish one from the other ?

The same question applies for a single photon : Is it possible to distinguish a unpolarized single photon from a H or V polarized photon ?

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: Considering a beam of light consist of photons, all coming from the same direction and all traveling in the same direction, how can a beam of light have 50% horizontal and 50% vertical polarized photons? Coherent or not how is a a dual polarized beam created? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the beams are white-light beams, the answer is "no", the two can't be distinguished from each other.  In the original form of this answer, I wrote:

> If they are coherent monochromatic beams, then they can be
>   distinguished from each other by analyzing their polarizations.  Beam
>   A would be vertically polarized, while Beam B would be polarized
>   circularly, elliptically, or linearly at 45 degrees.

which is not really responsive to the question. More accurately:

A coherent monochromatic beam has an unchanging polarization state: circular, elliptical, or linear.  It can't really be said to be unpolarized, because by using an appropriate combination of wave plates it can be transformed to any desired polarization state.  So, Beam B and Beam A are effectively the same: feed Beam B through a suitable combination of wave plates and it will be identical to Beam A. The details of how the vertical and horizontal (linear) components of B are combined, and the polarization state of A, will determine what the combination of wave plates needs to be.  In other words, there is ***not*** a way to distinguish the two beams.

A beam that does not have a definite polarization state must have a range of frequency components, with different frequency components having different polarizations.  Then, the *net* polarization in the beam at any instant is effectively random -- but then the beam is not monochromatic or coherent.

> The same question applies for a single photon : Is it possible to distinguish a unpolarized single photon from a H or V polarized photon ?

This is a bit different, because a single photon can only be measured once, whereas a beam can be measured many times.  For a single photon the answer is "no".

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still don't understand how you can make a difference between the two beams, even in the case of coherent monochromatic beams.
How do you do to analyze their polarization ? You wrote that beam A would be vertically polarized while I wrote that it is not polarized at all. Which filters do you propose to use ?

Comment: I will edit my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is clearer but I'm still in trouble because of @EmilioPisanty answer.

Comment: I think @EmilioPisanti and I gave essentially the same answer, but in different words.  The essence is in his statement, "it's important to note that unpolarized single photons are only possible if you allow your system to occupy mixed quantum states, which can be undesirable in several circumstances."  A mixed quantum state in this sense is not coherent.  It would need to span multiple wavelengths.  You mention an EPR source, so do you mean that the photons are emitted in entangled pairs?  If so, this changes the question substantially.

Comment: "A mixed quantum state in this sense is not coherent. It would need to span multiple wavelengths" - no, that second part is completely incorrect. A mixed quantum state is indeed incoherent, but it need not have any relationship with the monochromaticity of the beam. To make a source of monochromatic photons in a mixed polarization state, simply flip a coin to determine whether to send a H or a V photon.

Comment: Ah so.  I assumed you were referring to a mixed *frequency* state.

Comment: @EmelioPisanty, please confirm this is a way to form a monochromatic Beam A: Feed a 45-degree linearly polarized monochromatic beam into a Mach-Zehnder interferometer. Beamsplitter 1 is polarizing  and beamsplitter 2 is non-polarizing. Two monochromatic beams emerge with (opposite) randomly mixed polarization.

Comment: @S..MacGraw Mis-spelled names don't ping people ;-).

Comment: The apparatus you've described will *not* produce an unpolarized beam - it will produce a fully polarized beam whose ellipticity and angle of polarization will depend on the relative phase between the two arms of the interferometer. If you're trying to build a "monochromatic unpolarized beam", you're in danger of painting yourself into a corner, depending on exactly what you mean by 'monochromatic'. If by the term you mean a truly coherent Dirac-delta frequency spectrum, then no, an unpolarized beam is impossible. (cont.)

Comment: On the other hand, if you're OK with a nonzero bandwidth, then yes, it's possible, and one way would be to take your interferometer and add to one arm a phase modulator that added a randomly-changing phase with a correlation time $\tau=1/\Delta\omega$. (That would induce a bandwidth $\Delta\omega$ in the order of GHz for an EOM say, or kHz-MHz for an AOM.) If your measurement integrates over times longer than $\tau$, then the beam is effectively unpolarized. (But also: you then have enough in-principle frequency resolution to tell that the beam isn't monochromatic.)

Comment: @S.McGrew you do a better job of answering this question but I still wonder about the OPs “Beam B”. Can a beam be created where ONLY horizontal and vertical photons reach the analyzer? if not then how can this question be answered?

Comment: I'd suggest that you pose this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This

> beam B is composed of half H polarized photons + half V polarized photons

is an insufficient specification of the polarization state of beam B, because you do not specify whether the two sources are combined in a coherent or incoherent fashion.

- If the two components are **incoherent**, then the combination is unpolarized, and it is indistinguishable from beam A.
- If the two components are **coherent** with each other, then their superposition will be fully polarized, but the polarization state of the combination will depend on the relative phase of the superposition.

  If the two beams are in phase (in the usual convention) then the combination will be linearly polarized along an axis at 45° from both, and rotating a linear polarizer will produce a Malus-law pattern that will allow you to distinguish it from beam A.

  If the beams are 90° out of phase, on the other hand, then you will have a circular polarization, and you will need a circular analyzer to provide a suitable benchmark.

Either way, if the combination is coherent (or even partially coherent) then the thing to do is to perform a full polarization tomography measurement on the combination to measure its [Stokes parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters), which encode the full information about the polarization of the beam.

---

As for the second half,

> The same question applies for a single photon: Is it possible to distinguish a unpolarized single photon from a H or V polarized photon?

it's important to note that unpolarized single photons are only possible if you allow your system to occupy [mixed quantum states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states), which can be undesirable in several circumstances.

The core of your question, however, is one of *quantum state discrimination*, and it's not completely a trivial question.

- If you have a single copy of the photon, then it cannot be done.
- If you have multiple copies then you can pass the photon through a polarizing beam splitter and measure the output. If you get hits on two channels, then you know it's not a single such polarization, whereas if you only get hits on a single output port, then the more hits you get the more confident you can be about the purity of the state along that polarization.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is very clear and understandable but I'm still in trouble because of @S.McGrew answer.

Talking about beams, photons are supposed to be emitted by an EPR source so they are coherent, both in beam A and in beam B.


Talking about single photons ok. I agree (by the way, it drives me to another question about the possibility to figure out if a single photon is in a quantic superposed state or not (i.e. it is unpolarized or not). But since this is a related but different question I am going to create a new one).

Comment: Beam A, which you've described as unpolarized, cannot be coherent. Coherence requires a definite polarization.

Comment: Constructive feedback obviously welcome.

Comment: *** Please excuse me for the delay of my answer. I was out for a while ***
Ok. I have mixed up different things.
Beam A comes from an EPR source which is supposed to produce random polarized photons.
Beam B comes from a same EPR source, but half has been filtered with a H polarization filter, and half has been filtered with a V polarization filter.
I understand that if the two beam B sources are **phase coherent** their combination is polarized.
I don't know all Stokes parameters of the light provided by the EPR source. I have to dig deeper, but you helped me a lot.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I’m not sure if I have constructive feedback but would like clarification. Are you saying a single photon can be unpolarized? If so how can that be? Also how can you form a single beam of light with only horizontal and vertical polarized photons. I mean when you run light through a polarizer it all comes out polarized the same. How do you get dual polarization? Thanks

Comment: @BillAlsept Ask separately.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It sounds like you’re saying a photon can  have no polarization. How can this be considering polarization is a property of individual photons?

Comment: @BillAlsept Which part of "ask separately" was unclear? Your query is already addressed in the answer text, and this thread is **not** the venue to ask for extended clarifications. **Ask separately.**

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I’m not sure why you always need  to be such a smart aleck. I was asking about YOUR answer which is in THIS thread. It wasn’t really a separate question. Some of your answers usually need clarification. It sounded like you were claiming photons could have no polarization and I wanted to be sure but never mind.

Answer (score -1):

> … we have got two light beams. Beam A is not polarized at all. Beam B is composed of half H polarized photons + half V polarized photons. Is there any way to measure those two beams in order to distinguish one from the other?

That’s easy. Take polarization filter (designed for the range of the wavelengths you use) and measure the light behind the filter. The trick is to rotate the filter. In the case of the unpolarized light, the intensity of the light beam is not changing. In the case of half V- and H-polarized light the intensity is swelling four times for a 360°-rotation.

> The same question applies for a single photon : Is it possible to distinguish a unpolarized single photon from a H or V polarized photon?

No and yes. For a single photon it is impossible, see the answer from S. McGrew. For a stream of single emitted photons a statistics with measurements under different angles of rotation of the filter will show a swelling amount of measured behind the filter photons (for the V- or H-polarized photons) or a equally distributed statistic for nonpolarized photons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still doubt.
Since Sin(angle)^2+Cos(angle)^2=1 the light intensity shouldn't swell while you rotate the polarization filter behind beam B, should it ???
I was under the impression that some assymetric polarizer would be required, so that the 90° angle between the two half of beam B could change, but I don't know if such an assymetric polarizer exists…

Comment: Good point. Use a trick. Take a filter near the used wavelengths, which than should be transparent not for 90° rotation but only for 30°  . I’m curious, please stay in contact with the results. Or is it only a theoretical question?

Comment: At this point this is still a theoretical question. I am thinking about a device for which I need to make the difference. I have got other tracks but this one would be the simplest.
I am afraid that using a 30° filter wouldn't change anything because whatever the angle, Sin(angle)^2+Cos(angle)^2 still equals 1.
I may be wrong, of course...

Comment: "In the case of half V- and H-polarized light the intensity is swelling four times for a 360°-rotation" - that's completely incorrect. There is absolutely no polarization state of a monochromatic beam that will produce this behaviour. If you're thinking that you'll get two lobes per polarization and that those will add up to produce four lobes, then you're plain wrong: Malus's law tells you that each set of two lobes will behave as $\sin^2(\theta)$ and $\cos^2(\theta)$ respectively. If you add them together you very much don't get a four-lobe pattern.

Comment: And as for the "trick" that you mentioned - the filter you've described is physically impossible. @Bizniouf's observation is right on the dot, the method just won't work.

Comment: I’m asking in this question [Transmittivity of polarizing filters for different wavelengths with less than 50%](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/439760/transmittivity-of-polarizing-filters-for-different-wavelengths-with-less-than-50) about clarification for the case of no sine function for transmittivity of filters.

Comment: @Emilio Would you like to attend to my related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/439760/transmittivity-of-polarizing-filters-for-different-wavelengths-with-less-than-50, please?

Answer (score -2):

- If the 2 parts (H and V)of beam B are in phase (they come from the same source along the same distance), then H+V polarization = diagonal linear polarization.
  That can be easily seen with a linear polarization filter.
- If the 2 parts (H and V)of beam B  come from the same source but are dephased you get an elliptic polarization $\to$ can be seen with a circular polarized filter.

> The same question applies for a single photon : Is it possible to
>   distinguish a unpolarized single photon from a H or V polarized photon
>   ?

A single photon must always be polarized

Comment: Your last statement is incorrect - it applies only to single-photon *pure* states. It is perfectly possible to produce single photons in mixed states that are basically fully de-polarized.

Comment: what you mean @EmilioPisanty is that the polarization can be  *undertermined* until it's measured right ? If so there is still a polarization.

Comment: No. In such a configuration, saying that "there is still a polarization" is a counter-factual statement which is not within the statements that can be made in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Please elaborate because I dont know how you can talk about a (EM) wave that has no polarization. That would mean that the EM field have no direction, meaning they are 0, meaning it's a constant(not a wave).
In QM you are not supposed to talk about both a particle and a classical wave in the same time. But if you break the rule and allow yourself to give a wave property like polarization to a particle like a photon, then be consistent.
EDIT: in other words, you can either say a photon always has a polarisation or never. But not "sometimes".

Comment: @ Manu I would recommend looking up "unpolarized light" in your favourite optics textbook or web resource; if you want a specific pointer, the Wikipedia page is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves)#Unpolarized_and_partially_polarized_light) and a good in-site link is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31971). It is a perfectly standard concept and (since it is necessary to explain most light sources that you'll encounter in everyday light) it is explained in depth in any introductory resource to polarization in optics.

Comment: And as for "giving a wave property like polarization to a particle like a photon" - yes, this is perfectly possible. Photons are elementary excitations of different modes of the EM field (in the same way that electrons are elementary excitations of the electron field) and those modes are polarized; the photon simply inherits that polarization. If you want to go beyond that hand-wavy explanation and you want something more concrete, then I commend you - and I recommend that you pick up any good introductory textbook on QED. My favourite is *Photons and Atoms*, by Cohen-Tannoudji et al.

Comment: from the wiki link you gave me 
"Natural light, and most other common sources of visible light, are incoherent: radiation is produced independently by a large number of atoms or molecules whose emissions are uncorrelated and generally of random polarizations. In this case the light is said to be unpolarized. "

As you can see "unpolarized light" is the sum of random polarized light. It's not hard to understand in this context that a photon (unlike light) is not the sum of anything and therefore is always polarized.

Comment: Single photons can be in mixed states, which can be fully depolarized (as I've pointed out since my first comment). If the material confuses you, put in some serious study time with a textbook, or ask separately. I won't spend any more time in this thread fixing gaps in your knowledge that you can't be bothered to fix yourself. All of this is basic standard material that should be considered a prerequisite to answer questions like this one.

Comment: I read some more (http://idol.union.edu/malekis/QM2004/qm_spin.htm) , and surprise, i'm right, the mixed states (that I rightfully called indetermination) only exist *before* measurement but not upon it. A detected photon is always polarized.
You seem to have more knowledge than understanding.

Comment: @ManudeHanoi  your physical intuition is refreshing but reasoning with someone who can’t even imagine a photon as something real and physical is a waist of time. He will spout  probabilities but never give you physical example of how a single photon could have no polarization.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty it is you that’s stubbornly confused. Obviously your answers are stated wrong and need clarification or your limited ability to visualize a real photon makes it hard for you to carry on conversations like these. Individual photons always have a polarization/spin. A source emits individual photons with random polarizations. That would be unpolarized LIGHT but the individual photons still have polarization. To be specific a vertically polarized photon will pass through a vertical slit but not a horizontal slit. Your so called mixed state still has photons with polarizations.